# ComboBox: Style content depending on property state

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datatrigger

There are some posts that might point to my problem, but then again I get stuck by other problems when I try to apply their solution to my task.

So, I want a ComboBox to show a number (PathID) from my Path-class. Path has a property called PathState, which is an enum that can be PathState.red, PathState.blue, PathState.green, indicating a color.

I'd like to create a simple hardcoded list of type Path, just for learning, and then populate the ComboBox. I'd like to create three Path-objects with increasing ID, giving each a distinct color by asigning the PathState property.

By starting the app, the ComboBox should consist of the numbers 1, 2, and 3, whereas 1 is red, 2 is green, 3 is blue.

I know I need to get to it via ComboBox.ItemTemplate, DataTemplate, and DataTrigger - I just don't know where to start.

```
public class Path
{
  public int PathID {get;set;}
  public PathState PathState { get; set;}
}

public enum PathState
{
   red = 0,
   green = 1,
   blue = 2
}
```

EDIT: OK, I've made some effort, but are stuck on the DataTrigger-Part: here is my code:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbTest" ItemsSource="{Binding MyPaths}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="cmbText"  Text="{Binding PathId}" Foreground="Red"/>
            </DataTemplate>                
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyPaths}" Value="MyPaths.PathState">
                     <!-- Actually, I don't know how to continue beyond this point) -->
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Start with creating an `ItemTemplate` that contains a `DataTemplate`. then define `DataTrigger`s in your data template. Which particular questions and answers did you read and what is unclear to you?

Comment: As a beginner it's hard for me to be more specific - I guess I'm missing some terms. Please look at my Edit; especially the DataTrigger-segment - there my TargetName cannot be found. I hope this will be explanatory.

Comment: @SelfBiased_Resistor Can you be more specific as to what exactly you want to style (the items in the combobox, the combobox depending on the selected item, something else depending on the selected item, ...)? Does the style depend on whether the combobox is open oder closed? How do you expect the selection colors to behave? Is it relevant or do you just care about the color for not focused items?

Comment: @grek40: Actually I want to color of the ComboBox-Items depending on the state of PathState-property (if it's set to red, the color of the shown item should be red, if it's set to green, the color of the item should be green, and so on). So if you click on the combobox, and it opens up, you should the the item state by it's color (later on the colors shall stand for infos, like, red items for open tasks, green items for finished tasks and so on),

Comment: @dymanoid: sorry for that line of code - it's been there to test behaviour, but it has no relevance to my problem; I edit it out. Thanks for pointing out. Instead of Visibility I was trying out Foregroundcolor, which of course did not work. Thanks for keeping up with me; I hope I could narrow down the problem in my last comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF ComboBox color item according to property Mvvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920233/wpf-combobox-color-item-according-to-property-mvvm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a `IValueConverter` that converts from your `PathState` to the corresponding `System.Windows.Media.Brush`. Use predefined `Brushes`(https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brushes?view=netframework-4.8) unless you need something special.

Then instantiate the value converter somewhere in your resources (could be at any parent level, I put it in `ComboBox` only for this example. Then use the converter to bind your color to display properties.

If you want the `Background`, do it within `ItemContainerStyle`. If you want `Foreground` put it wherever its needed. Beware: my example puts Foreground=Background, you won't see much.

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <local:MyColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter"/>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PathID}" Foreground="{Binding PathState,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding PathState,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Yes sir, thank you very much - that did the job for me!